# Key Adapter Not Working But Focused

Tags: java, keyboard

I need help to improve my simple game of Tron. I first created Snake for a project and then decided to create this since I thought it would be somewhat similar. However, even though I used pretty much the same code for the key adapters in both, Snake's works but Tron's doesn't. If it makes any difference Snake was coded in JGrasp and Tron in Eclipse. Based on what I can tell from debugging the key adapter is not responding at all which made me think it was a focus problem but Tron's codes requests focus at all the same times Snake does and as I said Snake works fine. If someone could help me with that it would be great.

Also since I am relatively new to coding I would love suggestions afterwards on how I could improve the program in speed, or taking less memory. Also, any suggestions you have on features I should add to the game or ways I can make the game just look better, I would be very grateful to hear them. I might need help making these features especially if they introduce new concepts so I might contact you afterwards looking for help on how to do somethings.

Anyway here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Tron_Board extends JPanel{
   public int directionleft = 4;
   public int directionright = 3;
   static JLabel instr, Lwins, Rwins;
   public int numL, numR = 0;
   static int[][] array;
   static JLabel[][] board;
   Timer timer;
   public final int rows = 100;
   public final int columns = 200;
   JButton resetButton, quitButton, startButton;
   public Tron_Board()
   {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      array = new int[rows][columns];
      board = new JLabel[rows][columns];

      JPanel north = new JPanel();
      north.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      Lwins = new JLabel("" + numL);
      north.add(Lwins, BorderLayout.WEST);
      Rwins = new JLabel("" + numR);
      north.add(Rwins, BorderLayout.EAST);
      instr = new JLabel("Best of 5! Good Luck!");
      instr.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      north.add(instr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      Lwins.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
      Rwins.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
      instr.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
      add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      JPanel center = new JPanel();
      center.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
      for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
         for(int c = 0; c < array[0].length; c++)
         {
            array[r][c] = 0;
            board[r][c] = new JLabel();
            board[r][c].setOpaque(true);
            center.add(board[r][c]);
         }
      add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      JPanel south = new JPanel();
      south.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
      resetButton.addActionListener(new ResetListener());
      resetButton.setEnabled(false);
      startButton = new JButton("Start Round");
      startButton.addActionListener(new StartListener());
      startButton.setEnabled(false);
      south.add(resetButton);
      south.add(startButton);
      quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
      quitButton.addActionListener(new QuitListener());
      south.add(quitButton);

      addKeyListener(new Key());
      setFocusable(true);
      requestFocus();
      timer = new Timer(75, new Listener());
      reset();
   }
   private void start()
   {
      timer.start();
      startButton.setEnabled(false);
   }  
   private static void update()   
   {
      for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
         for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
         {
             switch(array[r][c]){
             case 0: board[r][c].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
             break;
             case 1: board[r][c].setBackground(Color.RED);
             break;
             case 2: board[r][c].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
             break;
             case 3: board[r][c].setBackground(new Color(13, 182, 233));
             break;
             case 4: board[r][c].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
             break;
             case 5: board[r][c].setBackground(new Color(169, 212, 144));
             break;
             }
         }
   }
   private void move()
   {
      int oldR = 0;
      int oldC = 0; 
      int newR = 0; 
      int newC = 0;
      int oldR2 = 0;
      int oldC2 = 0; 
      int newR2 = 0; 
      int newC2 = 0;
      for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
      {
         for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
         {
            if(array[r][c] == 1)
            {
               oldR = r;
               oldC = c;
               switch(directionleft){
                  case 1: newR = oldR - 1; //up
                     newC = oldC;
                     break;
                  case 2: newR = oldR + 1; //down
                     newC = oldC;
                     break;
                  case 3: newR = oldR; //left
                     newC = oldC - 1;
                     break;
                  case 4: newR = oldR; //right
                     newC = oldC + 1;
                     break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
       for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
      {
         for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
         {
            if(array[r][c] == 3)
            {
               oldR2 = r;
               oldC2 = c;
               switch(directionright)
               {
                  case 1: newR2 = oldR2 - 1; //up
                     newC2 = oldC2;
                     break;
                  case 2: newR2 = oldR2 + 1; //down
                     newC2 = oldC2;
                     break;
                  case 3: newR2 = oldR2; //left
                     newC2 = oldC2 - 1;
                     break;
                  case 4: newR2 = oldR2; //right
                     newC2 = oldC2 + 1;
                     break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
               if((array[newR2][newC2] == 0) && (array[newR][newC] == 0)){
                   array[oldR][oldC] = 2;
                   array[newR][newC] = 1;
                   array[oldR2][oldC2] = 4;
                   array[newR2][newC2] = 3;
               }
               else if((array[newR2][newC2] > 0) && (array[newR][newC] > 0)){
                   roundLose("draw");
               }
               else if(array[newR2][newC2] > 0){
                   roundLose("right");
               }
               else if(array[newR][newC] > 0){
                   roundLose("left");
               }

   }
   private void gameWin(String player)
   {
      timer.stop();
      instr.setText("Congratulations, " + player + " player won!");
      resetButton.setEnabled(true);
   }
   public void roundLose(String player){
       timer.stop();
       if(player.equals("left"))
       {
           if(numR + 1 == 3)
           {
               gameWin("right");
           }
           else
           {
           numR += 1;
           }
       }
       if(player.equals("right"))
       {
           if(numL + 1 == 3)
           {
               gameWin("left");
           }
           else
           {
           numL += 1;
           }
       }
       if(player.equals("draw"))
       {
           instr.setText("DRAW!!!");
       }
       reset();
   } 
   private void reset()
   {
      timer.stop();
      directionleft = 4;
      directionright = 3;
      Lwins.setText("" + numL);
      Rwins.setText("" + numR);
      instr.setText("Best of 5! Good Luck!");
      for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
         for(int c = 0; c < array[0].length; c++)
         {
            if(r == 0 || r == (array.length - 1) || c == 0 || c == (array[0].length - 1))
               array[r][c] = 5; //wall
            else
               array[r][c] = 0; //background
         }
      array[rows / 2][7] = 1;
      array[rows / 2][columns - 8] = 3;
      update();
      startButton.setEnabled(true);
      resetButton.setEnabled(false);
      requestFocus();
   }
   private class Listener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         move();
         update();
      }
   }
   private class ResetListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         reset();
         numL = 0;
         numR = 0;
      }
   }
   private class QuitListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
   private class StartListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         start();
      }
   }
   private class Key extends KeyAdapter
   {
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
      {
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                directionleft = 1; 
                System.out.println("I'm here");//up
         }
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) //down
            directionleft = 2; 
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) //left
            directionleft = 3; 
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) //right
            directionleft = 4; 
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
             directionright = 1;
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
             directionright = 2;
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
             directionright = 3;
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
             directionright = 4;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite on-topic for SO. Might I recommend [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? Only the first part of your question (a specific coding problem) is on-topic here. General code-review questions/requests for improvement suggestions should go to CodeReview.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Thanks for the recommendation! That being said are you able to answer the first part of the question? I've been trying a lot of things and still can't get the key listener to respond. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I put it in a JFrame under Java 8u91 on Windows 7 and the key listener works for me.

How are you using the panel and have you tried running from outside Eclipse?

Comment: I've fixed it now, apparently the start button was drawing focus away from the key listener when pressed. I was running it with a driver I had set up but I was unaware there are ways to run these java programs outside of something like JGrasp or Eclipse, how do you do it?

Comment: Assuming you have a driver program with a main method, from the command line: java MainClassName
though you may need the full path to "java" if it's parent directory is not on your system PATH.

If you turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages" in jGRASP, "actual command sent" in the output will show you exactly what command it is using to run.